# Tick box doesnt show in internet explorer

Tags: html

Sorry I've never come across this problem before.

My check boxes dont appear in IE but do in FF. Why? I dont know a second way to do tick boxes.

```
    <%if termandcon = "" and not error="" then warningman = "You Must Tick This Box"%>
    <span class="nobor pad_5 rtalign"  style="font-size:14px;">
      <input   type="checkbox"       name="termandcon" <%if termandcon = "on"then%> checked <%end if%> style="height:1px; width:1px;"/>
      <a href="/info/contactus.asp#term" target="_blank">
        <b> I accept the terms & conditions</b>
      </a>
    <span class="redtxt">*</span>
    <%warning(termandcon)%></span>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a tag. Your code is definitely no pure HTML. Which templating language are you using? Also it might be useful to paste the resulting HTML source code.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="termandcon"  style="height:1px; width:1px;"/>

Comment: What's the point to the 1px/1px size ?

Comment: Right.

style="height:1px; width:1px;"

gives me a small checkbox in FF but doesnt show at all in IE.

Comment: The behavior should be undefined when applying appearance attributes to check-boxes/radio-buttons

Answer (score 2):

```
 <input 
     type="checkbox" name="termandcon" 
     <%if termandcon = "on"then%> checked <%end if%>
     style="height:1px; width:1px;"/>
```

don't you see anything strange here? 
height:1px; width:1px;

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the style portion then it should work fine.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="termandcon" 
    <%if termandcon = "on"then%> checked="checked" <%end if%>/>
```